# Terminate Skype video call Android

Tags: android, skype

I launched a call using skype api with this code :

```
Intent skype = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");

            skype.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
            skype.setData(Uri.parse("skype:" + user_name +"?call&video=true"));     
            startActivity(skype);
```

and I wanted to finish this call by clicking a button that is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is as easy as:

```
if (skype.ActiveCalls.Count > 0)
{
    skype.ActiveCalls[1].Finish();
}
```

Just put that code in the button listener part and that's it.

Comment: Seriously? Your `Intent` object is the only one that have a public `ActiveCalls` property.